Why is it "Ernie and Bert" in German but "Bert and Ernie" in English and other Germanic languages?
I am aware that "Ernie and Bert" is used too, but "Bert and Ernie" seems to be the more common usage in English.
So I was wondering if certain attributes of the German language lead to it being only (!) known as "Ernie and Bert".

I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting. The names are pronounced differently in German, and German and English speakers may have different preferences when it comes to meter, but it seems to me any more specific answer would be speculation. Can you explain why English speakers don't say Hardy and Laurel? Costello and Abbott? Lewis and Martin? Laurie and Fry? Chong and Cheech?

I do not think that there is a really conclusive answer. Only the producers of the German adaptation could tell us why they changed the English "Bert and Ernie" to the German "Ernie und Bert" (and whether it was a deliberate decision at all).
The first TV broadcast of the German adaptation took place on January 8, 1973. I doubt that 51 years later a reliable clarification is possible and I do not see any special feature of the German language which could be the reason for changing the order of the names. Most certainly it was the personal preference of a single person.
Anyway, here is a wild speculation what could have influenced this person. My theory is that it was inspired (perhaps unconsciously) by the  quite popular German vocal duo Cindy and Bert. Doesn't it sound similar as "Ernie und  Bert"? Cindy and Bert started singing in 1965 and were most successful in the beginning of the 1970s.
By the way, changing the order of a pair in other languages is not unusual. For example, "Laurel and Hardy" aka "Stan and Ollie" got

Dick and Doof (German)
El Gordo y el Flaco (Spanish)
De dikke en de dunne (Dutch)

